# MVC 3 - RAZOR VIEWS - C# - Seperate _Layout.cshtml for Home Page from Other Site Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, layout, razor

How do you create a seperate _layout.cshtml for a HomePage design that is not formated the same way as internal pages.

e.g. - http://michcampgrounds.shadowinteractive.com - Home Page Template
I do not want to use the slider at the top for the internal Content pages.

Is it possible to call one _layout.cshtml for the Homepage;
While calling another _layout-content.cshtml for the content pages?

what would be the proper syntax to use for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to override the layout in the view you want.

**/Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_layout.cshtml";
}
```

Or you could do it in the controller

**/Controllers/Home.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ViewResult result = this.View();
  // i think this is correct and it shouldn't need a full/relative path
  result.MasterName = "_layout.cshtml";       
  return result;
}
```

This is assuming your _ViewStart.cshtml files looks like:

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_layout-content.cshtml ";
}
```

Comment: i just want to add my 2 cents to eriks answer,
if u want to decide which layout to use before getting to 
the control you can use the startPage.cshtml for example and ask 
@{if(request.IsAuthenticated) Layout = ******; else Layout = &&&&;}

Comment: I will test this out, and let you know the results.
@Liran - I will try this out also, thank you for your input.